# How to get size of element foreach loop by getting from the `$html->find('section[class="default-match-block"]')`?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

How to get size of element foreach loop by getting from the `$html->find('section[class="default-match-block"]')`?

```
<?php
include_once('../simple_html_dom.php');

function scraping_IMDB($url) {
    // create HTML DOM
    $html = file_get_html($url);

    // get title
    $ret['Title'] = $html->find('title', 0)->innertext;

    // get rating
    $ret['Game Title'] = $html->find('div[class="match-section-head"]', 0)->plaintext;

    // get overview
    foreach($html->find('section[class="default-match-block"]') as $div) {
        // skip user comments
        $ret['Name'] = $div->find('a',0)->innertext;
       print $ret['Name']."<br />";
    }

    // clean up memory
    $html->clear();
    unset($html);

    return $ret;
}


// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// test it!
$ret = scraping_IMDB('http://www.example.com');

foreach($ret as $k=>$v)
    echo '<strong>'.$k.' </strong>'.$v.'<br>';
?>
```

Comment: What is it `size`? Have you tried `count`?

Comment: No i don't have any idea regarding this because i am a new in php. I am an android developer.

Comment: @u_mulder does you need the url to check?